# How do I automatically open/close location or quickfix lists when they are populated by ALE?

Tags: vimrc, autocmd, quickfix, plugin-ale

I'm switching from the syntastic plugin to the ALE plugin. In syntastic there was an option `g:syntastic_auto_loc_list` that would automatically open the location list after it had been populated. If all errors were fixed that location list would close automatically again.

I have looked over the ALE documentation but have found no such option, so I tried to do it myself.

Specifically what I want is this:

- Open the quickfix and location lists automatically when there are any entries or when they have been altered.
- When opening a list, the list should appear as a horizontal split in the tab that the relevant file is in. Some of my attempts would spam all lists in the first tab, I don't want that.
- Do not open the qf/loc lists if the buffer is hidden.
- Close the corresponding list(s) when a buffer becomes hidden or is closed.
- If the last file is closed and there is a corresponding list open, then vim should quit.
- If the last file in a tab is closed and there is a list open, that list should close and the tab should be deleted as well.
- Close the list(s) if they are/become empty
- Don't open lists for readonly files, nothing I can do about it anyway, so there is no point wasting screen space.
- When lists are opened, they should never get focus, unless I manually switch to them, so that I don't get interrupted while typing.

I found `cwindow` and `lwindow` would show/hide the quickfix/location lists automatically but they need to be invoked. So I tried autocmd. The problem is I can't figure this out at all. Here is what I tried:

```
augroup AutoCAndLWindow
    autocmd!
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost [^l]* nested cwindow | setlocal nowrap | redraw!
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost l* nested lwindow | setlocal nowrap | redraw!
augroup END
```

This doesn't do anything at all. When ALE gets around to populate the list, the window doesn't open.

```
augroup AutoCAndLWindow
    autocmd!
    autocmd InsertEnter,InsertLeave,BufWritePost * cwindow | lwindow
augroup END
```

This throws an error at me:

```
Error detected while processing InsertLeave Autocommands for "*":
E776: No location list
```

I think this is because it tries to open a location list for the quickfix list.

I also want the location/quickfix windows to close when the corresponding buffer is closed or hidden. I like it to work with tabs and splits. I have found a few examples on the internet such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39307414/10263660), but that throws errors at me when I close a tab with a quickfix open for a file I'm editing.

How do I achieve what I want?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I can sympathize, I also switched to ALE recently. Syntastic remains one of my favorite pieces of software ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try the following two options:

```
let g:ale_open_list = 1
let g:ale_keep_list_window_open = 0
```

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. How embarrassing. Thank you. Sadly this doesn't close the list when the buffer it belongs to is being closed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Welcome to Vim :-)

Comment: @FalcoGer about the closing issue: it's not really what you ask but maybe something like `nnoremap <C-L> :cclose<CR><C-L>` may help you. I usually add some more commands and hijack redraw to make all visual clutter go away (the idea to do so is of course stolen from tpope's vim-sensible).